# Visualize a process instance history in Activiti

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management

I'm using Activiti 5.22.0. 
After my process completed, I want to draw the diagram of a process instance with the history highlighted tasks. 
I'm following to this post [Easy way to visualize a process instance history?](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/219990-easy-way-to-visualize-a-process-instance-history)

But I'm quite new to this so I really don't know how to write the code to my class. Can you tell me how to write or give me a example class.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

How are you running your processes? Do you have a Java app with Activiti 5.22.0 running your processes? 
If not you will need to create a maven project with the activiti dependency and then create a web page to display the diagrams. Following the tutorial that you linked. If you haven't created a Java app in the past, that will be challenging for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I design a process in Eclipse, I have a service task before end task to draw diagram with highlighted flow and save to hard drive as a png file . I followed the tutorial and had no idea what I have to do next to save the diagram.